# Is it good practice to use HTML forms to display data?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I am planning on using the form-control classes from Bootstrap to display data.

I have an inclusion template tag that generates a "form" from objects in the DB.

Is this a good practice? Or should I be investing my time in searching for a better way to display data?

Comment: i think you can use django crispy forms.here https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I did generate the form and it does display correctly. But I'm wondering if it is the correct way to do it, or is there a better way?